# Obejct is keeping association after change foreing key at Rspec example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rspec

I'm trying to merge two or more registers with their associations for example: `worker.files.count #3`, notice that worker `has_many: files` (dependent_destroy association) and file model belongs to worker. I need to change the owner of the file by changing its foreign key. Then when I try to do:

```
Worker_2.files.count #0
File.onwer #worker_1
File.owner = Worker_2
File.save!
File.owner # Worker_2
Worker_2.files.count #1
Worker_1.destroy!
Worker_2.files.count #0
```

Seems it keeps association with its dependant destroy callback, despite of I change the owner, also consider owner is a polymorphic relation. I'm using `Worker_1.reload` before to destroy it so it can update associations and it's actually working but i'm not sure if it would be a good approach itself and if this is a normal behaviour. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is the expected behavior of `dependent: :destroy`. If the `files` association has already been loaded on `Worker_1`, then it will perform the dependent destroy by running `destroy` for each file in the cached association without requerying the database to ensure that they still belong to Worker_1. Alternatively, you could use `dependent: :delete_all`. This would instead run a SQL delete for all files with worker_id = worker1.id.

Comment: Or you could reload the record and reset the cache for its associated files before destroying it like this `worker_1.reload.destroy!`

Comment: Or if you don't want to reload the whole record, you can just reset the one association: `worker_1.files.reset` `worker1.destroy!`